# I want to execute a part of code for 100millisecond then stop for 100 ms and the again do the same using c++

Tags: c++, timer, sleep, interrupt, c++-chrono

I want to execute a part of code for 100 millisecond then stop for 100 ms and the again do the same using c++. I hvae tried sleep methods but that takes more than expected because they stop's the execution for a particular time and then executes the code, so total time = sleep time + execution time. But, i want to give 100ms for a code part to execute if it is not completely executed then take a pause for 100 ms and then continue the execution. I want to write this code in c++.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<thread>
#include<windows.h>

int ms=0, sec=0, mins=0;

void timerms(){
    while(true){
        ms++;

        if(ms==80){ // should be 1000 for ms
            sec++;
            if(sec==60){
                mins++;
                sec=0;
            }
            ms=0;
        }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

    }
}

int main(){

    //timer thread
    std::thread t1(timerms);

    //Thread for printing
    std::thread t2([](){
        while(true){
            //printf("%d ms\t\t%d sec\t\t%d mins\n", ms, sec, mins);
            std::cout<<ms<<" ms\t\t"<<sec<<"sec\t\t"<<mins<<"mins"<<std::endl;
        }
    });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It depends on the precision you'd like to have. The terminology should be "time slice". You may use the keyword to find some relevant frameworks, apis and discussions about it.

Comment: Also in your code, `ms` increments for each loop, but how do you know the execution time of one loop is 1 millisecond?

Comment: @LouisGo That is the real issue I want to generate an interrupt every 1 or 100 ms even if the function is completely executed or not.

Comment: Then it's a different question. It depends on your hardware platform (multi-thread or single-thread ..etc) and how precise you'd like for the interrupt. Please elaborate on your real world use case.